# java.lang.NullPointerException caused by a Vector

Tags: java

I 'm using a matrix where each element is a vector of object "Person". I defined my Person class.

In an other class (and in the same package), I declared ma matrix as the following:

```
Vector<CKYCell> [] [] Score= new Vector [length][length];
```

I want to know the size of each element of the matrix, I use:

```
System.out.println(Score[i][i].size());
```

But I have the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is there any one who could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ZouZou: So I have to browse the matrix and initialize each element as the following: `Score[i][j]= new Vector();`

Comment: You also probably shouldn't be using `Vector`; it's been mostly obsolete since Java 1.2. Use a `List` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Vector [][] is an array of nulls.  You need to allocate that actual vectors
and stuff them into the array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you create a **2 dimensional array of `Vector`s** here:

```
Vector<CKYCell> [] [] Score= new Vector [length][length];
```

but you leave it empty. The first time you try to dereference an item in it: `Score[i][i]` you will get the default value form the array which is `null`.

To add an item to your array you can simply do something like this: `Score[i][i] = myItem;`

Keep in mind that `Score` does not refer to a `Vector` but an **array containing `Vector`s**. `Vector` objects are also considered to be deprecated in most cases.